# How to get AWS book information?

Tags: amazon-product-api

I'm trying to get info like title, authors and image and I've been looking for that for some time! I have read the documentation but I have not been successful.

Doing this with Google is quite trivial, I simply require what I need directly in the URL, for example: https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=harry+potter

But I can't find a similar link in AWS services. Is there, in fact, any url where I can request book information?

I know Amazon.com retail is separate from AWS and I think I should use the Amazon product API. But how to do it?

Comment: Removed AWS tag since this is as you correctly point out in the last sentence unrelated to AWS, you will not find anything within the AWS services. And then this question is just asking for an off-site resource and is therefore off-topic

Comment: You're right, that went unnoticed. I'm really not that familiar with Amazon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an Amazon Web Services expert but I believe what you're looking for is here: https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/search-items.html

In short, you need more or less of this here:

1. Register an api key;
2. [Send a request](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/sending-request.html);
3. [Verify and consume response](https://webservices.amazon.com/paapi5/documentation/getbrowsenodes.html);